# Ввод времени и даты в форму

Tags: html, css, safari

Использую вот такую форму у себя на сайте: 
`<input type="datetime-local" name="time">`
Но `Safari` просто выводит ее как пустую строчку, а в мобильной версии какое бы время я ни выбрал, оно пишет

> Введите верное значение

И ничего не происходит. Как можно решить вопрос получения даты и времени?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: @Visman, а какую альтернативу можно использовать?